# python 3.4 shell, why need to reimport same module (never restart shell)

Tags: python-3.x, module

Today it happened to me multiple times. I was using Python 3.4.4 shell on win32. I imported datetime, and did some input like 'print(datetime.datetime.now().date())' and got output right. After a while, I had to type "import datetime" again in order to do similar work (like 'datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)')

I think the similar problem happened to me before with other module?

Can anyone explain? I was looking for answers here and google but with no luck.

Comment: That certainly doesn't happen unless you restart the interpreter.

Comment: I did not restart. The shell is the same one! Never happened to anyone?

Comment: It could happen if you played around with `sys.modules`. Or if you did another import that broke the old one, like `from datetime import datetime` (btw: I hate how this package is structured...).